# Pgfplots: Ending Tick Markers are Faded

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a simple question about how to remove "faded tick markers" in a simple pgfplot of mine.

My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-},
    xmin=40, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=14,
    xlabel={Grades}, ylabel=Frequency,
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.2)},anchor=south},
    y label style={rotate=90,at={(axis description cs:-0.2,0.5)},anchor=north},
    xtick={40,50,...,100}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
    extra x ticks={40},
    set layers,
    axis on top,
    ytick={0,2,...,14}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
    yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
    x post scale=1.25, y post scale=1.25,
    clip mode = individual
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following image:

[image]

Notice how the tick markers at 40 and 100 on the x-axis are faded in comparison to the other x-axis tick markers. As you can see, I tried all combinations of clipping with no results. I also tried stretching out the xmin/max values to 39 and 101, respectively, but the x-axis is not formatted properly. I feel like there's a more automated way of fixing this, and would love to hear anyone's suggestions.

Edit: I figured out my issue. I set \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} (it was set as compat=1.9 before) and my issue was resolved.

Comment: Just to be sure: Is it the same if you zoom in?

Comment: @mickep I checked that as well. The tick markers are still faded even upon zooming in.

Comment: Please add the code to make the snippet compilable, with the document class and the packages used with their options.

Comment: I can not reproduce this result.

Comment: @Rmano Sorry, I updated a stand-alone compile-friendly version above. It was creating this that led to determining my issue (see above edit). I'll remember to put the preamble as well next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem. For example, see my MWE below.
- with provided code sniped is not possible to reproduce your problem
- Of topic: your axis settings can be a bit simplified:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-},
    xmin=40, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=14,
    xlabel={Grades}, ylabel=Frequency,
    x label style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=south},
    y label style={rotate=90,at={(-0.2,0.5)},anchor=north},
    extra x ticks={40},
    ytick={0,2,...,14}, 
    tick align=outside,
    set layers,
    axis on top,
    clip mode = individual
                ]
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll remember this for next time. See my above edits regarding resolving my issue. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @BradHall, I see now :-). But why you solve your problem with `pgfplots` version 1.15 instead of recent 1.18 (as is used in my answer)?

Comment: Because I updated the answer before you commented. 1.15 was the version I chose after quickly scouring the internet. Whether it's 1.15 or 1.18, they both equally satisfy the initial problem. Thanks again.